# Why does a Cassandra query sometimes return one row and sometimes null?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

So I am new to Cassandra but I am experimenting some strange issues:

I run this simple query from a cassandra client:

`select * from emps where causality ='bb4148ef-e9ff-4794-9ab2-d0e55a005d59'`

And I get one record.
Now I have a java repository implementation that is running the same query without any exception or errors and I am getting "null" back, even if I can see that the generate query is correct

`2022-07-28T18:55:19.122+0300 DEBUG Executing CQL Statement [select * from emps where causality = ?]`

Even more if I remove the where statement everything is working:
`select * from empswhere limit 1`

Here is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface CassandraUserSpinRepository extends CassandraRepository<Emps, String> {
    // works correctly 
    //@Query("select * from emps limit 1")
    // 
    // returning null even if a record exist in db
    // i check and causality parameter is sended correctly
    @Query("select * from emps where causality = :causality")
    SpinResult findByCausality(@Param("causality") String causality);
}
```

Has anyone some idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have more than one replica configured on your keyspace, the most likely issue is that your replicas are out-of-sync. If your app is reading with a consistency level of `ONE` or `LOCAL_ONE`, it could be hitting a replica which doesn't have the data.

For replicas to be missing data, the nodes must get overloaded at times and drop mutations. You need to repair the nodes with a rolling `nodetool repair -pr`, one node at a time so as not to overload your cluster even more.

Additionally, we recommend that use a strong consistency of `LOCAL_QUORUM` for reads and writes. You can configure the default consistency on the Java driver with:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  basic.request {
    consistency = LOCAL_QUORUM
  }
}
```

Just add this to your `application.conf` or `application.properties`.

If your cluster is repeatedly getting overloaded, you should consider increasing the capacity by adding more nodes. Cheers!

Comment: You can't image how much time I spent here because it was not making any sense. I change the consistency level and now I get output. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. But you need to address the underlying issue that nodes are dropping mutations because they can't keep up with writes which means your cluster is overloaded. Cheers!